# docker-compose spring boot can't connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am facing the weirdest issue ever, I have an spring boot application with postgres,

I deployed Postgres on docker and I have connect my spring application to it and everything went fine.

but when I try to docker-compose my application with Postgres it refuses to connect with this stack error

```
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:54.419  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:54.484 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
springbootapp_1  | 
springbootapp_1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.sulimanLab.AppointmentsSystem.AppointmentsSystemApplication.main(AppointmentsSystemApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      ... 58 common frames omitted
springbootapp_1  | 
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:54.485  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:54.502  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.307  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.309 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
springbootapp_1  | 
springbootapp_1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
springbootapp_1  |      at com.sulimanLab.AppointmentsSystem.AppointmentsSystemApplication.main(AppointmentsSystemApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[app.jar:na]
springbootapp_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:75) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
springbootapp_1  |      ... 56 common frames omitted
springbootapp_1  | 
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.310  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.310 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.319  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.322  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.336  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
springbootapp_1  | 
springbootapp_1  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
springbootapp_1  | 2020-01-06 10:53:55.339 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
springbootapp_1  | 
springbootapp_1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

appointmentssystem_springbootapp_1 exited with code 1
```

I will share my Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
ADD ./build/libs/AppointmentsSystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

and this is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.sulimanLab'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {

    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "5.0"
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql'


    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and this is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=appointmentSystem'

  springbootapp:
    build: .
    environment:
      - 'spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/appointmentSystem'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

lastly this is my application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/appointmentSystem
    username: postgres
    password: admin
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    database: postgresql
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

**------------------**

**NOTE**

when I build the jar file and run it alone it works, so I started to think that the problem came from dockerfile but I don't know, Please help.

Comment: Your postgres isn't running on localhost when deployed in docker, unless you are updating the Postgres container to include your jar, which I doubt. The URL should point to the name of the docker container containing Postgres.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, I expose the port on my local machine so it can be found when hitting localhost:5432, and the prove to that is I'm connecting to the database using DataGrip with url of localhost

Comment: That is from youyr local machine NOT from within the container.

Comment: I added this to spring boot environment environment: - 'spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/appointmentSystem' and still I get this error "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused." should not the environment overwrite the application.yml?

Comment: You should use `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as name for the environment, `spring.datasource.url` isn't allowed as a name (AFAIK `.` is not allowed in names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is trying to connect to `localhost:5432`. Instead you should connect to postgress service at `postgres:5432`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, I expose the port on my local machine so it can be found when hitting localhost:5432, and the prove to that is I'm connecting to the database using DataGrip with url of localhost

Comment: Your application is inside a container. Your local machine's `localhost` interface is different from the `localhost` interface inside your application's container.

Comment: I added this to spring boot environment     environment:
      - 'spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/appointmentSystem'
and still I get this error "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused."

should not the environment overwrite the application.yml?